# Elevation profile add-in for ArcGIS not producing graph

Tags: arcmap, elevation, add-in, python-addin

I am trying to create an elevation profile graph using a river line shapefile and the [add-in](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=e7d97dd9c005472a8ea887db8eb1366a) (with ArcMap 10.4.1). So I select my feature, click the "Create a profile for the selected feature" ("Finest" for DEM and blank for "Enter sample distance"). However I get this long error message :

[image]

***Edit***:

```
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\ESRI\Desktop10.4\AssemblyCache\*\elevationprofile_addin.py", line 152, in GenerateProfile AddGraph(postfix + sid - 1, dem_res, tempWS, tempOutTable, sid, lid, sendToService)
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\ESRI\Desktop10.4\AssemblyCache\*\elevationprofile_addin.py", line 188, in AddGraph arcpy.MakeGraph_management(graph_template, gr, out_graph)
File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.4\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 5851, in MakeGraph 'raise e'
RuntimeError: Object: Error in executing tool
```

It creates two .dbf files and one .cpg file in my scratch folder (also creates a table with 750 lines in my "List by Source" table of contents, but no graph to be found on ArcMap or the scratch folder.

For the record, I also get errors if I try to draw a line or change sampling distance or change DEM res.

Any clues what the problem could be?

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to include the error message in the body of the question as *text*, which makes it legible on all devices and searchable by others with the same problem.

Comment: Done-----------

Comment: Are you just looking for a profile of the elevation of a z enabled line?